# Importing JSON data into Django View/Template

Tags: python, django, json, import, django-views

So im working on a project and im using json data from a graphite graph and im trying to import it into the django views.py file and then get the value I want in the template. The import will be happening from a remote URL not from directly on the server itself.

here is my json:

```
[{"target": "stocks.shared (last: 4204.0)", "datapoints": [[4379.0, 1389225600], [4204.0, 1389312000]]}]
```

This is what my views file will look like

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['stocks'] = JSON PULL
    return context
```

I tried this and It did not work mostly because json open is not meant to pull externally.

```
json_data=open('URL')
context['shared'] = json.load(json_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `urllib.urlopen` to get external JSON data, like this:

```
from urllib import urlopen

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    my_stock_url = 'http://mystockpage.org/stocks/'
    context['stocks'] = json.loads(urlopen(my_stock_url).read())
    context['last_stock'] = stocks[0]['target'].split()[2].strip(')')
    return context
```

Comment: Thanks this works great!!! :) So now in my template I called {{ stocks }} Am I going to have to use django filters to filter that data? I really only want (last: 4204.0) that part but using cut is no problem for me :) This works for me was just gonna see if there was a more efficient way
`{{ stocks|cut:"[{u'target': u'stocks.shared (last: "|slice:":4" }}`

Comment: I suggest to parse the value in view. You could do it by ``stocks[0]['target'].split()[2].strip(')')``.